# Emulator doesn't feel like emulating if I ignore it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm curious if anyone else is experiencing this problem or if it's just me. If I don't upload to the emulator for a few hours it seems to lose all interest in participating in today's activities until I close it and relaunch it. `Android Studio` shows it running in the `Choose Device` dialog when I hit `Run`, it's state is `Online` but when I hit ok it never launches in the emulator. I even get the "Session 'app': running" popup in the bottom corner of AS. When I close the emulator I get "Error accepting connection, aborting" in the Run panel. If I run again and launch a new device everything will be fine and I can upload as much as I want until I leave it for an undetermined amount of time.

Is there a fix for this? It's not a huge deal to restart the emulator, it's just kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use your android smart phone to run your application. There is no need to launch any emulator. its faster too. Just make sure that while attaching  your smart phone to your Laptop/Desktop, you need to have phone driver in your Laptop/Desktop.